# Navigate between loosely related classes based on naming convention

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.1, code-navigation

In my current project we have many parts where we have something as follows:

```
var request = new ThingRequest {someId = };
ThingResponse response = dispatcher.Get<ThingResponse>(request);
```

Where dispatcher fetches a class with the name ThingRequestHandler that handles the actual logic.

```
public class ThingRequestHandler : RequestHandler<ThingRequest, ThingResponse>
```

This system is great for keeping it SOLID but I'm having trouble navigating easily.
Currently I use R# to goto class and -as I now the class name to follow convention- manually type the class name. This usually works but makes my head jump from thinking about the problem to thinking about a class name.

I would love to be able to navigate to my ThingRequestHandler from my dispatcher.Get line with one keystroke or click.

Is there a way Visual studio 2012, R# or any other plugin or macro would help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

In R# 8+ they made a loads of improvements and especially to the navigation. They introduced [CamelHumps](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__CamelHumps.html) which could be very useful in your case. For example you could navigate to `ThingRequestHandler` just by typing `trh`.

Comment: That is indeed the next best thing, was looking for more direct support though